# Term for a function from ℕ to ℕ where every element of the codomain is hit infinitely many times?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The sequence [A000120](https://oeis.org/A000120) is a familiar example of such a function. For other examples, see the answers to this question: [Existence of a sequence that has every element of $\mathbb N$ infinite number of times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328821/existence-of-a-sequence-that-has-every-element-of-mathbb-n-infinite-number-of)

Comment: I'm not aware of any term for such a thing.

Comment: Perhaps an "infinity-to-one function". E.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599921/countable-infinity-to-one-function

Comment: "infinity-to-one" is what I was thinking of.